# Verifying DNS TXT record (using Advanced setup mode) from godaddy while configuring firebase hosting for static website

Tags: dns, godaddy

I am migrating my static website from google storage bucket to firebase hosting. While connecting to domain to my app, I'm facing an issue with verifying the domain, which is hosted on godaddy.com.

I chose "Advanced" option while connecting the domain. Took the TXT records provided. (Attaching the image for reference)

Host:

```
_acme-challenge.www.samyojya.com
```

Value:

```
FPgE9th-jSlDgZXxQXySd1GDnU4l1LaZr1dSYnBJz24
```

The records are not also showing up on DNS dig tool. Looking like there's a problem with the way TXT record is configured on godaddy.com

I tried with both keys *_acme-challenge.www.samyojya.com* and *_acme-challenge*

Not able to resolve yet.

Comment: Please provide the domain name do we can run checks. Any information you publish in DNS should not be considered confidential as its publicly available. Specifically, doing this with a challenge key is not a problem as a dns lookup does not give control of the domain - which is the point.

Comment: www.samyojya.com

Comment: Updating TXT records can take a minute (or rather, sometimes ~5-10 minutes).  You should be using `_acme-challenge` for the TXT record itself. Furthermore, you can use e.g. `nslookup -q=TXT _acme-challenge.samyojya.com` to check whether a record has updated (just run it at intervals). For instance, it now returns the (probably now outdated) challenge you were likely having issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that I was trying to configure www.samyojya.com instead of samyojya.com. The DNS wasn't configured to map www.samyojya.com to samyojya.com. So, I first configured the challenge for samyojya.com. And I tried pointing both the A records, www.samyojya.com and samyojya.com to firebase provisioned IP's. It's resolved now!

**Note:** Instead of creating A-records for www, we can also configure CNAME for www to point to domain.